# E: The repository 'file:/var/nv-tensorrt-repo-cuda10.2-trt7.0.0.11-ga-20191216 Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

I wanted to remove `tensorRT 7`

`/var/nv-tensorrt-repo-cuda10.2-trt7.0.0.11-ga-20191216`

which use to getting updated when I was installing `tensorRT 6`

`sudo apt-get update`

so I removed `sudo rm -rf /var/nv-tensorrt-repo-cuda10.2-trt7.0.0.11-ga-20191216`

then again when I tried to use `sudo apt-get update`

I get this error message and update stops

```
Reading package lists... Done                                      
E: The repository 'file:/var/nv-tensorrt-repo-cuda10.2-trt7.0.0.11-ga-20191216  Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`sudo apt-get clean` doesn't work

How to I reset the `sudo apt-get update` so that it will not pop this error?

[source to install TensorRT](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html#installing)

Answer (score 2):

My bad I again had to install `sudo dpkg -i nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu1804-cuda10.2-trt7.0.0.11-ga-20191216_1-1_amd64.deb`

then purge the package with `sudo dpkg -P nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu1804-cuda10.2-trt7.0.0.11-ga-20191216`

Worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

re-downloading and re-installing fixed the issue. I also had to run `sudo apt-key add /var/nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu2004-cuda11.3-trt8.0.3.4-ga-20210831/7fa2af80.pub` to add the key.